# Paste pre-set string with one key in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, macros, copy-paste

I've actually had this problem over the years with both Windows and Mac OS.  I have to believe there is an easy way to accomplish this, but for the life of me I haven't figured it out.

I have a string that I would like to pre-set and then have a single key (a function key?) on they keyboard paste that string whenever it is pressed.  An example use case is that I have a conference call number that I often paste into e-mails and meeting invites.  Instead of having to copy and paste it I'd much prefer it was just stored as a macro somewhere that could be easily pasted.

Is there built in functionality to do this or maybe an App that would get me there?

Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish this in Windows. VBScript or PowerShell should help, or better still AutoHotkey/AutoIt, or even paid apps such as [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com) (which bills itself as "TextExpander for Windows").

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html), but it only supports snippets (like `,eml`) and not shortcuts.

You could also create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as [DefaultKeyBinding.dict](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html):

```
{
    "~m" = (insertText:, "name@example.com"); /* option-m */
    "^i" = {
        "m" = (insertText:, "name@example.com"); /* control-i and m */
    };
}
```